# Nvidia Geforce on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia-geforce

So i have Nvidia Geforce 920m and ubuntu 14.04 OS. I tried to install Nvidia specific driver from oficial site... and from ubuntu drivers and in both cases OS boots but screen is black. Is there an alternative driver wich will work? (I know that upgrading to ubuntu 16 is a solution ... but i want to stay with this)

Comment: Please [edit] this page to change `wich` to `which` and `oficial` to `official`.  Please also capitalize `Ubuntu` and the word `I`.

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and log into the terminal.
- Unistall all currently installed nvidea drivers:

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
- Reinstall drivers:

  `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core`
- Finally reconfigure the X server:

  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
- Reboot:

  `sudo restart now`

Comment: I have curently installed xorg x server... It simply doesn't  use my videocard.... It uses my RAM.

Comment: here what      lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'     command shows 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1a6d
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1a6d